# How to extract specific string values in multi-lined event

Tags: perl, awk

This is my multi-lined event.  All I need to do is to create a csv file with Timestamp, User, ecid and RemoteIP values.  These fields are available in row1, row11, row14 and row16 in my multilined event.  I tried using AWK and was able to look for lines starting with User, ecid etc and was able to strip the Field 2 using

```
awk -F'[=:]' '/User|ecid|RemoteIP/{print NR ", " $2  }' filename.txt
```

but need to how how to get the timestamp which is on the row 1.  Also, need to know how to make these 4 values to appear in a single line delimited by a pipe.  I am looking for some input here in AWK or Perl

```
[2019-03-01T10:08:30.00] [OBIPS] [TRACE:1] [] [saw.httpserver.request.showrequest] [ecid: 90b8:1e:16:-800-000,0:9] [tid: 563620160] Request received.
Type: POST            Headers:
Connection=Keep-Alive
Content-Length=58
Cookie=ORA_BIPS_LBINFO=16938b9e78c
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36
X-BlueCoat-Via=56038f342870633d
X-Forwarded-For=10.132.198.91
            Request params:
bieehome
icharset=utf-8
User=bi_admin
Password=******
SessionID: 9n5be88r2b041s5s6toojpagruk7ums
ecid: 90b8:1e:16:-800-000,0:9
ThreadID: 5636201600
RemoteIP: 10.192.121.136
]]
```

## Ouptut

```
Timestamp | User | ecid | RemoteIP
2019-03-01T10:08:30.00 | bi_admin | 90b8:1e:16:-800-000,0:9 | 10.192.121.136
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I have included that in the output section of my question

Comment: @SaravananK, comments are NOT meant for showing expected samples, please add that in your post and let us know then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, will add non-one liner form with explanation of code shortly too.

```
awk  '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
  print "Timestamp | User | ecid | RemoteIP"
}
/^\]\]/{
  if(val){
      print val
  }
  val=""
}
/^\[[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/{
  gsub(/\]|\[|\..*/,"",$1)
  val=$1
  next
}
/User=/{
  sub(/.*User=/,"")
  val=val OFS $0
  next
}
/ecid/{
  sub(/.*: /,"")
  val=val OFS $0
  next
}
/RemoteIP/{
  sub(/.*: /,"")
  val=val OFS $0
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Timestamp | User | ecid | RemoteIP
2019-03-01T10:08:30 | bi_admin | 90b8:1e:16:-800-000,0:9 | 10.192.121.136
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk  '                                                     ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                                     ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS=" | "                                                ##Setting OFS(output field separator) as space pipe space for all lines of Input_file.
  print "Timestamp | User | ecid | RemoteIP"               ##Printing header mentioned by OP in request here, will be printed before Input_file gets read.
}                                                          ##Closing BEGIN section of awk program here.
/^\]\]/{                                                   ##Checking condition if a line starts from ]] then do following.
  if(val){                                                 ##Checking condition if variable val value is NOT NULL then do following.
      print val                                            ##Printing variable val here.
  }                                                        ##Closing block for if condition here.
  val=""                                                   ##Nullifying variable val here.
}                                                          ##Closing BLOCK for]] condition.
/^\[[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/{                               ##Checking condition if a line starts from [ digits-digits-digits then do following.
  gsub(/\]|\[|\..*/,"",$1)                                 ##Globally substituting ] and [ from 1st field.
  val=$1                                                   ##Setting value of val as $1 here.
  next                                                     ##Skipping all statements from here.
}                                                          ##Closing BLOCK for ^[ condition now.
/User=/{                                                   ##Checking condition if a line contains User=then do following.
  sub(/.*User=/,"")                                        ##Substituting everything till User=
  val=val OFS $0                                           ##Concatenating value of $0 to val here.
  next                                                     ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
/ecid/{                                                    ##Checking condition if a line contains ecid then do following.
  sub(/.*: /,"")                                           ##Substituting everything till : space in line.
  val=val OFS $0                                           ##Concatenating value of $0 to val here.
  next                                                     ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
/RemoteIP/{                                                ##Checking condition if a line contains RemoteIP then do following.
  sub(/.*: /,"")                                           ##Substituting everything till : space in line.
  val=val OFS $0                                           ##Concatenating value of $0 to val here.
}
END{                                                       ##mentioning END section of this awk code, this will be executed once Input_file is done with reading.
  if(val){                                                 ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
    print val                                              ##Printing variable val here.
  }
}
' Input_file                                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Amazing stuff.  This is just what I am looking for - Thanks

Comment: @SaravananK, Glad that it helped you, will add explanation too so that we all could learn from it, you could go through it and learn too, cheers.

Comment: The explanation was very useful.  What  I don't understand is the gsub part.    "##Globally substituting ] and [ from 1st field".  What is the significance of this?

Comment: @SaravananK, that is for timestamp line where your input has `[` or `]` so removing them by this command here.

Answer (score 1):

Use white space or `:` (followed by a white space) or `=` or `[` or `]` as field separators (FS). OFS is output field separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" |: |=|\\[|\\]"; OFS=" | "} 
     $5=="OBIPS"    {time=$2}
     $1=="User"     {user=$2}
     $1=="ecid"     {ecid=$2}
     $1=="RemoteIP" {ip=$2; print time,user,ecid,ip}' file
```

Output:

```
2019-03-01T10:08:30.00 | bi_admin | 90b8:1e:16:-800-000,0:9 | 10.192.121.136
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)